# How do I modify the value of an attribute with OpenLDAP?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

We have installed a mail server which comes with an OpenLDAP schema and some additional attributes. One of the attributes controls which users have administration rights on the calendar and public folders feature of the server. How do I set these attributes on our existing users in the LDAP database?

Comment: @David - what kind of mail system is this?

Comment: It's Zarafa (http://www.zarafa.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ldapmodify is your friend.

Create a "modify" ldif file.

Ex:

```
dn: cn=Elmer Fudd,o=company.com
changetype: modify
add: isAdmin
isAdmin: 1
```

Save file and use it with ldapmodify:

```
ldapmodify -v -D "cn=manager,o=company.com" -h <host> -W -f changes.ldif
```

Comment: I had to use simple authentication (-x) but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: For anyone trying it out now, to modify the value you need to use "replace: isAdmin" instead of "add: isAdmin".

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've discovered to do this is to use [gq](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gqclient). It's not the prettiest of applications, but does work reasonably well.

If you find yourself doing the same tasks over and over again, it might be worth writing a script in your favourite scripting language. In Perl you can use [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap-0.33/lib/Net/LDAP.pod).

Answer (score 1):

smbldap-tools and [SMBLDAP-TOOLS Addons](http://smbldap-addons.sourceforge.net/) are perl scripts to manage user and group 
accounts stored in an LDAP directory.

For examples: smbldap-attribute is a simple and powerful script. This script can add/modify/delete any attribute.

add attribute and value (support multiple values):

```
smbldap-attribute "uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com" "attribute:value"
smbldap-attribute "uid=user1" "attribute:value"
smbldap-attribute user1 "attribute:value"
smbldap-attribute -s "_" "uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com" "attribute_value"
```

modify value:

```
smbldap-attribute "uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com" "attribute:current:new"
smbldap-attribute "uid=user1" "attribute:current:new"
smbldap-attribute user1 "attribute:current:new"
smbldap-attribute -s "/" user1 "attribute/current/new"
```

delete value:

```
smbldap-attribute -d "uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com" "attribute:value"
smbldap-attribute -d "uid=user1" "attribute"
smbldap-attribute -d user1 "attribute"
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a Java based LDAP browser/Editor that was quite nice and easy to use.  It had not been updated in two or three years, and the link to it seems to have gone away.  Gowars was the author, and once you authenticated to a tree, it would allow you to edit entries in a UI which was nice.

Alas, it did not understand schema types, and thus all attribute values were entered freeform, with the expectation that you knew the correct syntax for each attribute.

I have the install binaries (Well Java based, so whatever you want to call them) but all links to the original site seems to be gone.  Which is a shame.